# Android: Ringtone is not visible in settings>Sound and Display>phone ringtone

Tags: android, ringtone

I have developed a sound board application, in which I set ringtones on long press. No issues about it. The ringtone is changed. But when i go to Settings->Sound & Display->Phone Ringtone my ringtone is not listed at all. And No ringtone is selected. How do I list my ringtone there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of ringtones is pulled from the system ringtones directory, as well as from the SD Card, if it contains a folder named "ringtones". So what you may try doing is to also copy the ringtone from your soundboard to the SD Card, into a folder called "ringtones" (first perform a check to see if the folder already exists) at the same time that you set the ringtone.

Comment: But I have another sound board application which lists the tones without making a copy in the ringtones folder or notification folder. How is that possible.

Comment: Hmm, I'm actually not sure about that, then.

Comment: Ok, I am doing it by placing the tones in their respective folders and it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If the ringtone does not show up, restart your phone and check again. Some versions of Android the "sound" is in "settings", then touch "audio profiles",then the checked profile, ie; "General" and you'll find "Voice call ringtone".

Answer (score 1):

On **Pixel 3** (**Android P - API 28**) I basically had to rename the file into a single word name. Something like *"NameOfYourRingtone.mp3"*. Uploaded it to the phone storage in the **"Ringtones"** folder. After swiping everything settings related away from the task manager and restarting the phone I saw my song under **"Phone ringtone -> My sounds"**. Its really sad that both "Play Music" and sounds don't have a better file change listener implemented.